# Difference between Hope and Believe?

Tags: word-choice

I was told that:

> 1) I **hope** to play a good match this evening.

is grammatically correct.

On the other hand:

> 2) I **believe** to play a good match this evening

is grammatically incorrect.

Yet I was told that:

> I believe **I´ll** play a good match this evening.

is grammatically correct.

Why is the previous sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: Your example #2 is not grammatically valid - it would have to be, for example, *I believe [that] **I will** play a good match this evening*. The semantic difference between *hoping* and *believing* is General Reference (you might well believe you're dying of cancer, but you probably wouldn't *hope* to be dying of cancer).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between HOPE and BELIEVE?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79092/difference-between-hope-and-believe)

Comment: So what dictionary explains that "believe" can't be followed by an infinitive? It seems like this question was closed based on its title and not the content of the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Hope** is about **aspiration**, wanting something **good** or **better**.

> **Hope** for the best

It is unusual to **hope for worse**.  Hope is one of the verbs that can be immediately followed by an [infinitive](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/verbs-followed-infinitives/)

**Belief** is about **affirmation**, **asserting** or **declaring** something to be true

> I **believe** in the goodness of mankind

**Believe** is not one of the verbs that can be followed by an infinitive.

As a result

> I **hope** to play
>   I **believe** I will play

are correct

> I **believe** to play

is incorrect.