# Difference between 'hope' and 'believe'?

Tags: word-choice

I was told I can say:

> 1) I **hope** *to play* a good match this evening.

On the other hand I *cannot* say:

> 2) I **believe** *to play* a good match this evening

I was told I can say the following:

> I **believe** *I´ll play* a good match this evening.

Why is that? Is there any rule for this?

Answer (score 3):

The English language is truly complicated at times. Too many options and too many exceptions to the rules! Rather than attempting to give you a few rules to which there will almost invariably be a few exceptions, I'll simply give you a number of ways to say the same thing, using the sentences you've provided.

The infinitive, *to play*, can function as a noun and as the subject of a sentence (technically, a predicate nominative), as in

> 1. To play a good match this evening is what I hope to do.

With the insertion of a few more words, including the word *that*, you can make your second sentence correct as well, as in

> 2. I believe **that** to play a good match this evening, I will need to bring my best game. [To bring one's best game is an idiomatic way of saying I intend to play my very best.]

Your third sentence is fine, as is. Moreover, the word *believe* could be substituted with the word *think*, with very little (if any) change in meaning. In other words, you can say either

> 3. I hope I'll play a good match this evening,

or you can say

> 4. I believe I'll play a good match this evening.

As for the difference in meaning between *hope* and *believe*, the words *I believe* have the ring of certainty to them, while the words *I hope* communicate less certainty than *I believe*.

Which of the following two sentences conveys more certainty?

> - I **believe** I'll attend the party tonight,

or,

> - I **hope** I'll attend the part tonight.

If you say the first sentence conveys more certainty, you're correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hope: something maybe can happen in your expectation.
believe : something will going to happen in your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

example: 
hope :
I hope she will come here (you are not sure she will come).
believe:
I believe she will going to come here (you are sure about that)

Answer (score 0):

believe gives some surety whereas hope doesn't yield good results.In hope we have less expectation while in believe we are confident of something.